# Algebra for geometric sum problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on a problem but I can't follow the solution's algebra, can you please point out how does the last two step occurred? (In red). The calculation switched 0.12 to 12/70 in one steps. And dropped the -1 term in one step.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(.12)(.7)^{m-1}(0.6)^{j-m-1}$$
$$(.12)(.7)^{m-1}\frac{(0.6)^{j-1}}{(0.6)^{m}}$$
$$(.12)\frac{(.7)^{m}}{(.7)(0.6)^{m}}(.6)^{j-1}$$
$$\frac{(.12)}{.7}\frac{(.7)^{m}}{(0.6)^{m}}(.6)^{j-1}$$
$$\frac{12}{70}(\frac{7}{6})^m(.6)^{j-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

\begin{align}0,12 (0,7)^{m-1}(0,6)^{j-m-1}& \\ &=\frac{12}{100}\frac{(0,7)^m}{0,7}\frac{(0,6)^{j-1}}{(0,6)^m}\\&=\frac{12}{70}\left(\frac{0,7}{0,6}\right)^m(0,6)^{j-1}\\&=\frac{12}{70}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^m(0,6)^{j-1}.\end{align}

In the first step we use $0,12=\frac{12}{100}$ and $a^{m-n}=\frac{a^m}{a^n}.$ In the second step we multiply $100\cdot 0,7=70.$ In the third step we use $\frac{0,7}{0,6}=\frac{7}{6}.$